# After fetching JSON data from an endpoint, how do I work with the response?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ajax, api

I'm attempting to implement basic notifications in my App. I have setup a `/notifications.json` endpoint that serves as an `index` that returns all `Notification` for the `current_user`.

*controller:*

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_user).unread
  end
end
```

*notifications.json view*

```
json.array! @notifications do |notification|
  json.actor notification.actor
  json.action notification.action
  json.notifiable notification.notifiable
  json.url thread_path(notification.notifiable)
end
```

*/notifications.json*

```
[
  {
    "actor": {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "test@user.com",
      "created_at": "2022-07-30T14:58:12.617Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-09-17T16:30:04.497Z",
      "name": "John Doe",
    },
    "action": "posted",
    "notifiable": {
      "id": 76,
      ...
    },
    "url": "/threads/76"
  }
]
```

Now to the JS part. I want to implement some sort of JS behaviour so when a page is loaded, the notifications are fetched and some HTML is replaced to show each notification in a dropdown (each notification being a hash from the array of hashes returned by the `notifications.json` endpoint).

I use StimulusJS for this part, so the controller is automatically connected when the HTML is loaded.

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "links", "template" ]

  connect() {
    this.fetch_notifications()
  }

  fetch_notifications() {
    fetch("/notifications.json")
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response)
        }
      )
  }
}
```

But this is as far as I can get. I've tried several things when working with the `fetch()` response but I haven't managed to get to the array of hashes that manually visiting `/notifications.json` returns.

*console.log(response)*

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/notifications.json", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/notifications.json"
__proto__: Response
```

*console.log(response.body)*

```
ReadableStream {locked: false}
locked: false
__proto__: ReadableStream
cancel: ƒ cancel()
getReader: ƒ getReader()
locked: false
pipeThrough: ƒ pipeThrough()
pipeTo: ƒ pipeTo()
tee: ƒ tee()
constructor: ƒ ReadableStream()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ReadableStream"
get locked: ƒ locked()
__proto__: Object
```

*console.log(response.json)*

```
ƒ json() { [native code] }
```

I was expecting to get the same array of hashes in the `response.body`, but I do not.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to further process the `fetch()` response?

Comment: you can try : `fetch(...).then(response => response.json()).then(data => { console.log(data) });`

Answer (score 0):

Notifications should be pushed by the server, not pulled by the client.[Hotwire](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams) is made for this. You don't need js or json.
On the initial page load, display the notifications (optional). (shown below using haml not html)

```
= turbo_stream_from current_user
#notifications
  = render @notifications
```

This assumes you have a partial called _notification.haml, look at the details of rendering collections [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections). The div with id `#notifications` is the container that will be used as a target for appending new notifications when they are created on the server.

The `turbo_stream_from current_user` statement establishes an actioncable channel identified by the current user.

When notifications are created, a callback broadcasts the notification to the user's browser, and you will set it up to append the new notification (using the _notification.haml partial) to the #notifications element.

```rb
#app/models/notification.rb
belongs_to :user

after_create do
  broadcast_append_to user, target: 'notifications'
end
```

This sends the notification as haml (or html) over the actioncable channel identified by the user.